# Converting Input type in JSP from text to check box

Tags: html, jsp, checkbox, inputbox

I have a text box in JSP as below:

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" readonly="readonly" NAME="IssueFlag" ID="IssueFlag" SIZE="45" class="allcaps" maxlength="49" value="<%=mySearchTO.getIssueFlag()%>">
```

It will display value Yes or No based on whether the flag is set or not.

I want to replace it with checkbox where the checkbox should be checked if the value is Yes else unchecked.

How can I put it ?

For e.g. in case of dropdown I am doing something like:

```
<select name="dropdown">     
    <option value="one" ${param.dropdown == 'one' ? 'selected' : ''}>One</option>     
    <option value="two" ${param.dropdown == 'two' ? 'selected' : ''}>Two</option>     
    <option value="three" ${param.dropdown == 'three' ? 'selected' : ''}>Three</option>   
</select>
```

But how to achieve such functionality with checkbox.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Scriplet,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxName" value"checkBoxValue" 
<%=mySearchTO.getIssueFlag()?"Checked":""%>
```

In EL,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxName" value"checkBoxValue" 
${mySearchTO.issueFlag()?"Checked":""}>
```

I prefer EL

Comment: Is 'value="checkBoxValue"' mandatory ? Because in my case, as you can see, it is of no importance.

Comment: same logic which used, use "Checked" instead of "Selected"

Comment: value is needed when you retrive checkbox value in server side

Comment: So since the value should be Yes or No depending on the flag being returned, can I put value="<%=mySearchTO.getIssueFlag()%>" ??

Comment: Yes.you may use el which you may aware of.

Comment: Sorry.. But its a really old legacy system. So can not use it.. getIssueFlag() might also return null. So will have to put that check as well.. can you please update your answer for it so that it becomes complete.. somehow am not able to edit..

Comment: I thought getIssueFlag() returns boolean datatype. isn't it?